# When is the best time to load state using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When is the best time to load state and in what order I am currently only initially preloading state when each component is mounted as below

```
export default {
 name: 'Tasks',
 mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch( 'fetchTaskLists' )
 },
 computed() {
  taskLists() {
    return this.$state.state.task.taskList;
  }
 }
```

Now the example above is working fine, however there are some things I have questions about or feel like a bit of an anti pattern.

Firstly, I also need things like user settings should I just dispatch extra actions?

Secondly, mostly all my dispatches make http requests, should I be firing at least 1 request per component mount. It seems like a lot?

**Edit:**  Just to confirm the above code is working as desired I have a store and mutations setup correctly. My questions are purely relating to best practices regarding when to fetch state and if it is bad practice to fetch state for most components.

Comment: When is the best time to load the state, this is a very good question, as it depends on what you need to do. The first thing you need to know when using vue is to know how the vue lifecycle works, why? Why this is the most important part of your code. Take a look at this flowchart to understand a little more. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: Firstly, I also need things like user settings should I just dispatch extra actions: Yes you can dispatch many action at "same time". Imagine you need get some data from your api... you can get this data inside your created function.... async created () { await this.$store.dispatch( 'fetchTaskLists' ) }

Comment: When you dispatch one action, you will need set one state before use your store... So you use your state to use computed properties inside your component. 
This is a goog kick stated couse with vuex to you improve your skills, take a look https://vueschool.io/courses/vuex-for-everyone

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueVanKlaveren, I am aware and getting to grips with the life cycle. I just want to keep in line with the best practices. I am currently loading all user settings on auth, which is fine. But I wanted to know is a page loading and all its components each sending 1 or 2, maybe more requests. Could lead to each page hammering my API many many times. Is there an already tried and tested better way to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you need update some data, or getting this for the fisrt time yes. You will needed make many requests. Another way is your create a init function to ran in your index and populate a start state with only one request. Its depend again what you need to do.

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren I see thank you I think that is my answer. I may have to move some none crucial loads out of mounted and into created and I have already started loading some initial state in from the global app created method. Happy to award some points if you would like to write up your answer?

Comment: Just set my comments as usefull I will be happy. I had glad to help you.